# The Power of Word Choice in Changing Perceptions

Tags: semantics

I am looking for any studies, research, or theories about how choosing particular words or descriptions can lead to perceptual changes and judgements. This would be like loaded or emotive language.

For example if a news headline were to state "President X attacks new tax plan". As opposed to "President X opposes new tax plan". The word difference here is attacks vs. opposes. "Attacks" is more aggressive, while "opposes" is more tame.

Or another example is if a news headline stated "drone strike leads to loss of innocent life." As opposed to "drone strike leads to collateral damage." This would be "loss of innocent life" vs. "collateral damage".

If you notice the messages are practically identical with the exception of the different word choices. I want to know if any studies, research, or theories demonstrate whether different word choices, such as what I demonstrated, will change are understanding and judgements of the information we receive. This is mostly in reference to online news article headlines but any study will suffice.